# Gelfond-Schneider Constant $2^{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Someone knows a proof (books , articles)  that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational ?

Without using that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendent.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138247/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt2-is-an-irrational-number-without-using-a-theorem .